# Dynamic Queues on RabbitListener Annotation

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'd like to use queue names using a specific pattern, like `project.{queue-name}.queue`. And to keep this pattern solid, I wrote a helper class to generate this name from a simple identifier. So, `foo` would generate a queue called `project.foo.queue`. Simple.

But, the annotation `RabbitListener` demands a constant string and gives me an error using my helper class. How can I achieve this (or maybe another approach) using `RabbitListener` annotation?

```
@Component
public class FooListener {

    // it doesn't work
    @RabbitListener(queues = QueueName.for("foo"))
    // it works
    @RabbitListener(queues = "project.foo.queue")
    void receive(final FooMessage message) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the context come from? Environment variable?

Comment: I've changed "context" for "queue-name" for clarifying. It's just a name. But I want to reinforce the name pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare a magic bean, in this case implicitly named `queueName`:

```
@Component
public class QueueName {
    public String buildFor(String name) {
        return "project."+name+".queue";
    }
}
```

Access this using a "constant string" that will be evaluated at runtime:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{queueName.buildFor(\"foo\")}")
```

Answer (score 14):

To create and listen to a queue name constructed from a dynamic UUID, you could use [random.uuid](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values).

The problem is that this must be captured to a Java variable in only one place because [a new random value would be generated each time the property is referenced](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7009).

The solution is to use [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) to call a function that provides the configured value, something like:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{configureAMQP.getControlQueueName()}")
void receive(final FooMessage message) {
       // ...
}
```

Create the queue with something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureAMQP {

    @Value("${controlQueuePrefix}-${random.uuid}")
    private String controlQueueName;

    public String getControlQueueName() {
        return controlQueueName;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue controlQueue() {
        System.out.println("controlQueue(): controlQueueName=" + controlQueueName);
        return new Queue(controlQueueName, true, true, true);
    }

}
```

Notice that the necessary bean used in the SpEL was created implicitly based on the `@Configuration` class (with a slight alteration of the spelling `ConfigureAMQP` -> `configureAMQP`).

Comment: That seems to work as an annotation, which is great.  But I don't see how to connect it to a configuration that creates the queue with the same random name.

Comment: @nobar assuming you are using spring boot you can easily use same random property in application.yml or  properties file - like `queue-name: someprefix-${random-uuid}`. You can use with `value`  annotation or SPEL in anywhere in your code.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion -- it seems like it should work for my case (although I'm still wresting with Spring trying to make it work).  It isn't as general as what the OP was trying to do, but perhaps it suggests that an elaborate general solution is possible with the right magic beans...

Comment: BTW: I assume you meant to type `${random.uuid}` -- is that correct?  I'm having trouble finding documentation for this (using either spelling).

Comment: You are welcome - Yes, it should be `${random.uuid}`. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values) and [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/RandomValuePropertySource.html). I can expand on the solution if you could further explain your problem.

Comment: You're not going to believe this, but using this in 'application.properties' (`app.id=${random.uuid}` `controlQueueName=${base.name}-${app.id}`, it generates a *different* UUID for the configuration (queue creation) vs. the listener.  There must be some magic syntax to lock it down to a single application-wide value.

Comment: Indeed there are some suggestions [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7009) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274032/spring-boot-configuration-how-to-return-always-same-random-value-when-reference). Perhaps will help you or else I will take a deeper look.

Comment: Based on those two sources, this appears to be a known issue: "property source should not be stateful"

Answer (score 5):

If `{queue-name}` would came from `yml` file - it should work:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue-name}")
public void receiveMessage(FooMessage message) {

}
```

Spring will inject value from `application.yml`.

Comment: Excellent response, simple solution