# Spring RandomValuePropertySource generates different values every time the property is referenced

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have an `application.properties` looking like this:

```
testPort=${random.int[40000,65000]}
url=https://localhost:${testPort}
```

while the `testPort` is injected into my integration test code to open a port where the application under test can send data to, the `url` is part of my normal configuration and injected into the productive code that sends the data to this url.

The issue is, that every time the testPort is referenced, it provides another value. Meaning the port that is opened by my test cases is another one configured in the url. Here is a minimalized example:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Value("${testPort}")
    int testPort;

    @Value("${url}")
    String url;

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println(testPort);
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

I would expect that the port in the url is the same then `testPort`, but the output is e.g

```
55576
https://localhost:43701
```

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274032/spring-boot-configuration-how-to-return-always-same-random-value-when-reference